# When reviewing answers, add the entirety of the question in the reading pane?

Tags: feature-request, review

Sometimes it is difficult to tell whether or not an answer (especially for first post users) has already been addressed by previous answers. An example here:

[image]

Here I am reviewing a user's first post.   It seems to simply answer the question asked. However, when navigating to that very same question...

[image]

As you can see, the currently accepted answer to that question has already listed what this new answer has, so this post brings nothing to the table. That said, for a person who has just been granted privileges to use the review queue, they may not be as able to understand the context within the question and its answers and could have trouble determining if this was a legitimate answer.

Could it be possible to at least add some context from the question to the review reading pane?

Comment: I just went through questions by people with tiny numbers of rep (ok, I'm not rich either) and saw nothing like that.   At least, not on StackOverFlow.